# Chrome web translation won't request "translate.googleapis.com"

Tags: google-chrome, google-translation-api

Version: 106.0.5249.119 x64 on windows 2008 R2

When right click > translate to XXX, no request occurred in DevTools "Network" tab, Why? All extensions disabled.

Comment: Assuming you are using the Google Chrome Extension,  You must have it enabled. And I would suggest to look in to your ad blockers or any blockers installed  in your browser.  Another possible factor in the version of windows you are using seems pretty outdated.

Answer (score 0):

I think I knew why, The reason is that the first access to `translate.googleapis.com` after opening the browser was unsuccessful, it cause the required scripts not being obtained, so subsequent translation will not fire requests.